# POSTing to another page in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, post, umbraco

Alrighty, I've asked this question of Umbraco forums and Umbraco support, let's see who wins the race if I ask stackoverflow too. =)

ASP.net provides [several](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for posting data to another page or usercontrol within your site, but they all seem to fail within Umbraco (at least that's how it seems when reading through Umbraco forum posts or trying them myself).

- I've tried using PostBackURL, but it's not-recommended in a couple of
  forum posts, and it seems to break the onclick of the other buttons on the page.
- I've tried using Server.Transfer, but it doesn't seem to work in a
  handler like Button onclick.
- I can't use Response.Redirect and put data in the GET query string,
  because there's a big chunk of data to transfer ... I need to POST.

Is there a recommended way of doing this for an Umbraco site?

Answer (score -2):

So If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to import / use an ASP .Net user control with umbraco? And the question is around you having issues trying to achieve this?

If so please comment on this answer and I will update with a solution.

Comment: No, I'm trying to post from a user control to a page using another user control. I'll change some verbiage to clarify.